# How to get the count of Microsoft Office files uploaded to SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-server

My Client's requirement is to extract the count of Microsoft Office files uploaded to the SharePoint

Environment: SharePoint 2013

Answer (score 0):

Execute the below query in your Content DB.

```
SELECT Extension as 'File Extension', count(Extension) as 'File Count' from AllDocs group by Extension having extension  IN ('accda','accdb','accdc','accde','accdp','accdr','accdt','accdu','acl','ade','asd','doc','docm','docx','dot','dotm','dotx','grv','laccdb','maf','mam','maq','mar','mat','maw','mda','mdb','mde','mdt','mdw','mpd','mpp','mpt','mso','olm','one','pa','pip','pot','potm','potx','ppa','ppam','pps','ppsm','ppsx','ppt','pptm','pptx','pst','pub','puz','sldm','sldx','slk','snp','svd','thmx','vdx','vsd','vss','vst','vsx','vtx','wbk','wll','xar','xl','xla','xlam','xlb','xlc','xll','xlm','xls','xlsb','xlsm','xlsx','xlt','xltm','xltx','xlw','xsf','xsn','vsdx','rpmsg','oft','obi','ost','onepkg','crtx','iaf','ops','oab','prf','xslb','h1q','cnv')
```

This will provide you the count of MS Office files uploaded to all the SharePoint Site Collections in the Content DBs.